# overhead of exec() call?

Tags: cgi, benchmarking, sh

I have a web script that is a simple wrapper around a perl program:

```
#!/bin/sh
source ~/.myinit // pull in some configurations like [PRIVATE_DIR]
exec [PRIVATE_DIR]/myprog.pl
```

This is really just to keep the code better compartmentalized, since the main program (myprog.pl) runs on different machines with different configuration modes and it's cleaner to not have to update that for every installation.  However, I would be willing to sacrifice cleanliness for efficiency.

So the question is, does this extra sh exec() call add any non-negligible overhead, considering it could be hit by the webserver quite frequently (we have 1000s of users on at a time)?  I ask, because I know that people have gone to great lengths to embed programs into httpd to avoid having to make an extra fork/exec call.  My assumption has been that this was due to the overhead of the program being called (eg mod_perl bypasses the extremely slow perl startup), not the process of calling itself.  Would that be accurate?

I've tried to benchmark this but I can't get the resolution I need to see if it makes a difference.  Any advice on that would also be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: any feedback on answer for 'overhead of exec() call?'  ;-)?

Answer (score 0):

Try a test?

Assuming you have a test environmentn separate from production.

*(and this is a little vague, and real testers will be able to amplify how to improve on this)*

- Run your current 2 level design in a tight loop, using the same param for 100,000? 1,000,000? ...
- Then 'fix' your code so the perl is called directly, with the same params as above, looping for same count.
- Capture performance stats for both runs. The diff between the two should be (roughly) the cost of the extra call.

If this works out, I'd appreciate seeing the results on this:-)

(There are many more posts for tag=testing than tag=benchmark)

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer

Answer (score 0):

It's easy for a perl program to take over some envars from a shell script, see the answer to [Have perl execute shellscript & take over env vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610672).
Using this there is no need for exec at all which should alleviate all your worries about exec overhead. :-)